# Using a refresh token to authenticate Firebase Admin

Tags: javascript, firebase, oauth, firebase-admin

I would like to authenticate firebase-admin using a refresh token. Here's what the Firebase docs have to say about this:

> The Admin SDKs also provide a credential which allows you to authenticate with a Google OAuth2 refresh token:
>
> ```
> var refreshToken; // Get refresh token from OAuth2 flow
>
> admin.initializeApp({
>   credential: admin.credential.refreshToken(refreshToken),
>   databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
> });
> ```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk)

So I tried doing this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.refreshToken({
    refreshToken: '6/m-jebiu2398bydhl2lhjdUehkEWlhewer', // fake value for security
    clientId: '2398757349827-bkewjeo7b092j2083hodb0u923.apps.googleusercontent.com', // fake value for security
    clientSecret: 'ijboi3290u8eu2132', // fake value for security
    type: 'authorization_code'
  }),
  databaseURL: 'https://<database>.firebaseio.com/' // fake value for security
})

admin.database().ref('/test2').once('value')
  .then(snap => snap.val())
  .then(console.log.bind(console))
```

(I ran this with Node.js)

*Note that `admin.credential.refreshToken` takes an object. The docs (guide and reference) don't say this. I only discovered this fact (and the shape of the object) by looking at the source of firebase-admin.*

This code doesn't throw any errors, but it does not work. Every few seconds, a warning appears in the console, and the `console.log` is never called in the `.then`. (Adding a `.catch` doesn't change anything, nor is the `.catch` triggered).

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.
```

Upon doing some more digging, this warning comes from @firebase/database, not firebase-admin. It occurs when Firebase database rejects the authentication (from the websocket connection).

In fact, firebase-admin successfully creates an access token, it's just that the database rejects it.

I tried two types of refresh tokens:

1. A refresh token created from a third party Google app (unrelated to the database). Of course I provided the related client id/secret too. *I assumed that the google user would have to have access to the project in order to authenticate like this*. This method creates the warning described above.
2. A refresh token created from the Firebase project (the project that owns the database). Again, the client id/secret come from the project that created the refresh token. This also creates the warning described above.

Having said all that, I have two questions:

1. Where should I get the client id/secret and refresh token, if not a third party app nor the google app created by Firebase?
2. What is the `type` that's passed to `admin.credential.refreshToken`? An empty value throws an error but literally any other string value seems to make no difference. The `type` doesn't seem to be used in the source of firebase-admin.

Now, you might ask "*Why* do you want to authenticate firebase-admin using a refresh token?". I would like to create a web app that can access any arbitrary database, if the owner/authorized user of the project gives permission. I believe this is the best way to go about that.

Thank you for taking the time to read all of this. I appreciate any suggestions you have!

Comment: I have the exact same error (for 2 days now). And I also tried the same code. I saw this issue at GitHub, more people are affected. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/147

Comment: @da1lbi3 thanks for the link. After reading through that issue, it appears to be more of a problem with Cloud Functions (I didn’t see anyone using a refresh token for auth). In your code, which project are you using to create the refresh token? A third party google project or the same google project that owns the database?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the credentials of a service account that's been given Editor permission in a the project that hosts the database(s) you want to access.  Actually I don't know if you can use a single credential for this, or you have to select the credential that's needed to access the project.

Comment: @DougStevenson "*It sounds like you want to use the credentials of a service account that's been given Editor permission in a the project that hosts the database(s) you want to access.*" Yes, exactly. "*I don't know if you can use a single credential for this, or you have to select the credential that's needed to access the project.*" I'm not sure what you mean by that. Where would I select the credential? In my code? In the Google Cloud Console? Or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The refresh token format expected by the Admin SDK is specific to Google products. This is the file format used by [`gcloud` SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). If you have `gcloud` SDK installed, and performed a [login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login) using it the required refresh token file gets created at `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`. You can pass this file path or the contents object of it to `admin.credential.refreshToken()`. The value of the `type` field is `authorized_user` by convention, but the Node SDK doesn't really care as you have noticed.

Refresh token credentials enable the SDK to authenticate as individual users. This is useful during development and testing (to use developer's credentials as a stand-in for application default credentials), but has no production applications as far as I know. You should probably use a service account for your use case.

Following worked for me (accessing a database that I own, with my own refresh token):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.refreshToken('~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json'),
  databaseURL: "https://<DB_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
});
admin.database().ref().once('value')
  .then(snap => {
    console.log(snap.val());
  })
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe the Firebase docs fail to mention the gcloud SDK or the login command.

Comment: I now have a question about `gcloud`: It looks like the client ID / secret are that of gcloud, not my project. (They don't match any of my projects, and seem to be the same for anyone using gcloud). Can I use one of my project's client ID / secet? I tried the `--client-id-file` flag but I get a python error: `ERROR: gcloud crashed (TypeError): object of type 'long' has no len()`

Comment: Do you know what the `client-id-file` should contain? I'm guessing it's not just the client ID (as the name would suggest). My "client-id-file" only has the numeric ID of my project, but that causes said error.

Comment: @Sidney As I said, this is not a common use case for Admin SDK. The documentation attempts to keep things focused by not including `gcloud` SDK in the mix. I believe the client ID used by the `gcloud` SDK is your own -- i.e. tied to you personal gmail/google account. It will allow access to any project that your account has access to (hence why it's not a good idea in production). The client ID format is something like `********.apps.googleusercontent.com`, if you wish to pass the `client-id-file`.

Comment: I initially  tried the full `********.apps.googleusercontent.com` (which includes the numeric ID) but I was getting another error, something about extra or unexpected characters past char 13 (the end of the numeric ID). I was hoping this would allow users to programmatically give my app access to their database, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll stick with service accounts.